# Google Drive or Google Photos: get a view count of my shared folders or files

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

How can I know how many people accessed a folder or file on Google Drive or Google Photos that I shared with a link?

Comment: Don't think you can, but you can get that information through most URL shorteners, including goo.gl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Share the folder or link through Google URL shortener (goo.gl). If you login to create short URLs, it always show all short URLs created through your email. You can check the detail of clicks from the given list of short URLs.
Even if enter `.info` at end of the short URL, it shows all details about link. Meaning, if the short URL is `goo.gl/QZ3qT7` then enter 
`goo.gl/QZ3qT7.info` in the URL bar and you will see number of clicks on link and other details as in screen shorts.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like they are going to stop that google url shortner. Here is the message I found on the website. `Starting March 30, 2018, we will be turning down support for goo.gl URL shortener. From April 13, 2018 only existing users will be able to create short links on the goo.gl console. You will be able to view your analytics data and download your short link information in csv format for up to one year, until March 30, 2019...` Here is a blog which explains about some alternatives. https://zapier.com/blog/best-url-shorteners/

Comment: (comment moved from an answer and shortened for brevity (*ed.*))